# how to change the version of android application

Tags: android, version

Hello i have problem with changing the android version for the application, i have made in the "Package Explorer" under the Project saying me `Android 4.2.2` but i have tried on some lower version like `4.1` and its working but when i try on `2.2` doesn't, how i can check what is the lower version of the version i can install the application and how i can change it to work from `2.2` to `4.2.2`
**EDIT:** I have tried to change the version going `Right Click on the project > Properties > Android > Android 2.2` but that doesnt work its showing me errors in folders `values-v11` and `values-v14`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values-v11 and values-v14 are version specific folders for API level 11+ and 14+ respectively.

Android 2.2 has no support for that, and hence the error.

*What I suggest you to do :* Keep the target SDK level as high as you want (Google encourages you to build against the latest SDK level). Change the **`minSdkVersion`** in your manifest file to enable the application to be run on devices with lower API level.

**`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="..." />`**

Comment: and what should i put there ??? already its `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

**EDIT:** Oh and yea i have tried that too i have put 3 and 9 thre but it was a some warning at the top of the code on this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: Keep target 17 and min 9. Go to properties and select 4.2 back again

Answer (score 3):

You can change the Android version (SDK) for the application in Manifest file.

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />`

API level 8 is for Android 2.2 and 18 is for Android 4.3

Save the Manifest file.

if error persist try clean the project from Menu `Project -> Clean...`

Comment: i have changed and doesn't showed me errors but now i can run the application in android 2.2 or higher version ?
but i have backed the Android 4.2.2 in the Package

Answer (score 1):

values-v11 and values-v14 are not available in 2.2 Android. Make sure you install android 2.2 sdk on your machine.

If you want to set minimum and maximum sdk for your application then you can add this in your androidmanifest.xml

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

If you want to build your project on 2.2 then go to properties(Right clicking on project)- then select Android and select 2.2. or whatever you want.

best suggestion is to build project on any version just set your minimum and maximum SDK.